# Convert pdf to text, remove the header, footers and images along with tables (python, Jupiter notebook or R)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, pdftotext

I want to convert the pdf to text, but the catch here is that I only require the text and should exclude tables, images, header and footer. The pdf doesn't have a specific format. So can't implement the hard croping rules to remove the headers.  *(python, Jupiter notebook or R)*
Please if anyone can help me out.